# java sub image display

Tags: java, image, layout, awt

I write a game with cards.  And I'm able to output with String.  However, I'd like to change the display of String into images.  I'm able to use JFrame and `GridLayout` to show four cards in 2*2 image.

My question is that I have a .png for the deck of cards, how can I get individual cards accordingly?

### Class `Card`

```
package Chapter7;

public class Card {
    Suit suit;
    Rank rank;

    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public Rank getRank() {
        return this.rank;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() {
        return this.suit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.rank + " of " + this.suit;
    }

    public enum Suit {
        CLUBS(1), SPADE(2), HEARTS(3), DIAMONDS(4);

        int value;

        Suit(int v) {
            this.value = v;
        }

        int getSuit() {
            return this.value;
        }
    }

    public enum Rank {
        ACE(1), DEUCE(2), THREE(3), FOUR(4), FIVE(5), SIX(6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10), JACK(11), QUEEN(12), KING(13);

        int rank;   

        Rank(int num) {
            this.rank = num;
        }

        int getNumber() {
            return this.rank;
        }
    }
}
```

### Class `Deck`

```
package Chapter7;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import Chapter7.Card.Rank;
import Chapter7.Card.Suit;

public class Deck {
    List <Card> deck = new ArrayList <Card> ();

    Deck() {
        for(Suit s : Suit.values()) {
            for(Rank r : Rank.values()) {
                deck.add(new Card(s, r));
            }
        }
//      System.out.println("A new deck created!!!");
//      for(Card c : this.deck) {
//          System.out.println(c.toString());
//      }
    }

    public void shuffle(){
        this.deck.clear();
        Deck ret = new Deck();
        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            int j = (int) (Math.random() * (52-i));
            deck.add(ret.deck.remove(j));
        }
//      System.out.println("After shuffle!!!");
//      for(Card c : this.deck) {
//          System.out.println(c.toString());
//      }
    }

}

package Chapter7;

import java.io.IOException;



public class Game {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.shuffle();
        int aGame = 4;
        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
            if(aGame == 1) {
                System.out.println(deck.deck.get(i).toString());
                System.out.println("Start!!!");
                while (true) {
                    char c = (char) System.in.read();
                    if (c == '\n') {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                aGame = 4;
//              if(i == 51) {
//                  deck.shuffle();
//                  i = -1;
//              }
            }
            else if(aGame == 4) {
                System.out.println("Calculate based on the following four cards!");
                System.out.println(deck.deck.get(i).toString());
                aGame --;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(deck.deck.get(i).toString());
                aGame --;
            }
        }
    }



}
```

### Class `LoadImageApp`

Class to load image in 2*2 `GridLayout`.

```
package Chapter7;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * This class demonstrates how to load an Image from an external file
 */
public class LoadImageApp extends Component {

    BufferedImage img;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public LoadImageApp(String s) {
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File(s));
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
             return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
           return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2, 2);
        f.setLayout(grid);

        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        f.add(new LoadImageApp("27.jpg"));
        f.add(new LoadImageApp("hw6.jpg"));
        f.add(new LoadImageApp("27.jpg"));
        f.add(new LoadImageApp("hw6.jpg"));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

How should I change these two classes to display?

The .png with deck of cards is here.

http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c13/s1.html

Comment: `"Please specify with code."`??

Comment: User BufferedImage's `getSubImage(...)` method, but that's about all the code "specification" I can do for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me try it out!

Comment: It works great!!!! Millions of thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad you've got it working!

Comment: One additional question, I got the picture(with four cards) shown, but I'd like to stop on this picture till I click on it or press enter, how should I change my program.

Comment: Currently, it's using while {} as input to console. But I'd like to change to more user-friendly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a .png for the deck of cards, how can I get individual cards accordingly?

Use the `subImage(..)` method as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861852/add-a-complex-image-in-the-panel-with-buttons-around-it-in-one-customized-user/10862262#10862262).

[image]

That is a single image broken into 9 sub-images.  4 are used for the buttons (with an alternate 'red bordered' icon for the pressed state) and 5 for labels.